# Checked null value of dateTime in REST API SharePoint

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint-online

I need to check null values of DateTime field in REST API SharePoint. In the documentation I found "Date eq null", but I got the error: "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable".
I tried "undefined" too, but I got the same error.
Thank you so much!

I would like to know another way of resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should work. Could you please check that you are using the internal name of your Date Field. Also, please provide your full REST Query that you are trying to run along with error screenshot.

and alternate to check the null value can be as follows

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YourListTitle')/items?$filter=YourDateTimeField eq datetime'1900-01-01T00:00:00Z'
```